# How to ensure uniqueness of a property in a NoSQL record ( Golang + tiedot )

Tags: go, unique, tiedot, nosql

I'm working on a simple application written in golang, using [tiedot](https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/tiedot) as NoSQL database engine.
I need to store some users in the database.

```
type User struct {
    Login        string
    PasswordHash string
    Salt         string
}
```

Of course two users cannot have the same login, and - as this engine does not provide any transaction mechanism - I'm wondering how to ensure that there's no duplicated login in the database when writing.

I first thought that I could just search for user by login before inserting, but as the database will be 
used concurently, it is not reliable.

Maybe I could wait for a random time and if there is another user with the same login in the collection, delete it, but that does not sound reliable either.

Is this even possible, or should I switch to a database engine that support transactions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I first thought that I could just search for user by login before inserting, but as the database will be used concurently, it is not reliable.

Right, it creates a race condition. The only way to resolve this is:

1. Lock the table
2. Search for the login
3. Insert if the login is not found
4. Unlock the table

Table-locks are not a scalable solution, because it creates an expensive bottleneck in your application. It's why non-transactional storage engines like MySQL's MyISAM are being phased out. It's why MongoDB has to use clusters to scale up.

It can work if you have a small dataset size and a light amount of concurrency, so perhaps it's adequate for login creation on a lightly-used website. New logins probably aren't created so frequently that they need to scale up so much.

But users logging in, or password changes, or other changes to account attributes, do happen more frequently.

The solution for this is to make this operation atomic, to avoid race conditions. For example, attempt the insert and have the database engine verify uniqueness and reject the insert if it violates that constraint.

Unfortunately, I don't see any documentation in tiedot that shows that it supports a unique constraint or a uniqueness enforcement on indexes.

Tiedot is 98% written by a single developer, in a period of about 2 years (May 2013 - April 2015). Very little activity since then (see https://www.openhub.net/p/tiedot). I would consider tiedot to be an experimental project, unlikely to expand in feature set.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've already switched to à SQLite back-end as I didn't want to waste more time trying another solution. I felt too confident regarding the 1000+ stars on github, my bad... Thank you for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Below is my solution. It is not Tiedot specific, but It uses [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and can be applied to various DBs.

You can also have other benefits using it, such as caching and bulk write (in case DB supports it) to prevent asking DB on every request.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "log"
    "errors"
)

type User struct {
    Login        string
    PasswordHash string
    Salt         string
}

type MutexedUser struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    Map map[string]User
}

var u = &MutexedUser{}

func main() {
    var user User

    u.Sync()
    // Get new user here
    //...
    if err := u.Insert(user); err != nil {
        // Ask to provide new login
        //...
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

func (u *MutexedUser) Insert(user User) (err error) {
    u.Lock()
    if _, ok := u.Map[user.Login]; !ok {
        u.Map[user.Login] = user
        // Add user to DB
        //...
        u.Unlock()
        return err
    }
    u.Unlock()
    return errors.New("duplicated login")
}

func (u *MutexedUser) Read(login string) User {
    u.RLock()
    value := u.Map[login]
    u.RUnlock()

    return value
}

func (u *MutexedUser) Sync() (err error) {
    var users []User

    u.Lock()
    defer u.Unlock()
    // Read users from DB
    //...
    u.Map = make(map[string]User)
    for _, user := range users {
        u.Map[user.Login] = user
    }
    return err
}
```

Comment: So you literally read the whole database table into memory as a map? What happens when your table is too large to fit in application memory?

Comment: Also if this is a web app, you could have this code running hundreds or thousands of requests concurrently. But if you mutex access to the map, you've just caused your website to run requests serially.

Comment: Not necessarily to keep all database, could be logins only. Also I'm using  u.RLock() to minimize awaiting time for reading requests. And yes, I do have thousands requests concurrently.

Comment: Right, enforcing uniqueness on a login name is one thing. The table is likely to be small, and new logins created can tolerate some serialization. But this is not a general solution for uniqueness in any column of any table.

Comment: Sure, it is in context of current task only. I'm using this approach mostly alongside with microservice architecture, when every service requires its own database.

Comment: @n00dl3 I believe I answered your question. It is -"**How to ensure uniqueness of a property in a NoSQL record ( Golang + tiedot )**" and not like -"Should I use SQL or switch to something else". Please clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry if i made you waste your time, but keeping the whole user collection in memory would have been too expensive for what I wanted to do. Note that the end of my question is "or should i switch to a database engine that supports transactions ?". I voted-up your answer, but as your solution has a non-negligible cost and as I was already thinking about switching to another DB engine, I don't think i can consider it as "best answer".

Comment: I simply want other people to find a correct solution. By the way the memory consumption for 100K user logins is less than 5Mb and the performance is a way far better than any not in memory DBs. Thanks for vote-up

Comment: I also upvoted your answer, since it provides a working solution, although one that I believe does not scale up to real-world scenarios. But kudos anyway for going to the trouble of writing the code.